# Call stored procedure in the Order By clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query :

```
Select 
    Name, city, ID  
from 
    company 
order by 
    NoOfEmployees desc,....
```

The next criteria I would like to add to the Order by, involves calling a stored procedure (`spGetDependencies`) which takes the `ID` as the parameter and counts the number of dependencies. I need to sort the results by the number of dependencies in descending order.

How do I achieve that?

edit: Will be using a UDF in the order by clause. Thank you for your help.

Thanks

Comment: How does the [stored procedure return data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15)? "[O]utputs a number" isn't very specific. Perhaps a [user-defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Correct. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to the `order by` clause:

```
select name, city, id 
from company 
order by NoOfEmployees DESC, dbo.spGetDependencies(id) desc
```

Comment: Except for the fact that stored procedures cannot be called as part of a `SELECT` query. If it was a UDF it could.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yes. I understand the question is more related to a function than a procedure (otherwise, the statement "outputs a number" does not make sense in the first place).

Comment: That's correct. I am a C#/VB programmer and most of the time I execute the sp as scalar and store the result in a variable in the code most of the time. But this is happening within SSMS so the wording of this question should have been different. I will create a UDF  and use it in the Order by clause. Thank you for the answer.